# Using variabled in include not working fat-free

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm working on some project of mine but what i want to do isn't working. Basicly : in a script i set the variable @views, and then in the rendered file i put this :

```
<include href="{{@views}}blocks/navbar.html"/>
```

`{{@views}}` isn't transformed to the @views variable content ! It is just showing up `{{@views}}`. After that, F3 gives me an error because, of course, there is no file named `{{@views}}blocks/navbar.html` !
How can I fix this ? (*If the variable is tranformed, the file exists.*)

Comment: Are you even using he Template class? It looks like your using the View class instead.

Comment: No, I am using the template class !

Comment: It's probably related to github issues [#842](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/842), [#873](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues/873) and [#62](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/pull/62). Try `{{ @views.'blocks/navbar.html' }}` instead.

Comment: Okay, solved. Thanks @xfra35 ! Only thing is that that's very, very, very annoying !